# Short story about a precognitive person that is unable to say how to stop an alien invasion?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I remember reading this short story in 2016 on the app I Funny about this person who could see the future. They tell how they knew the winning lottery numbers, which horses would win a race, things like that. But then he goes on to say how when "they" came(I assume he means aliens), he went up to a stage with a large crowd. They waited for his plan to stop the invasion, but even with his psychic ability, there was no way to stop it so he had to lie to the crowd. The "beat drop", if you will, of the story was saying how there was no way to stop them. I have been searching and searching for over a year trying to find it, but I just can't. I think part of the story says he was famous for his ability and possibly wrote a book(but the story itself is not a book, just a one page story)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Sounds a little like [*The World Jones Made* by Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Jones_Made). The inevitable alien “invasion”; the protagonist delivers his “prophecies” about this to a large crowd; and I seem to recall a book written by him propels him to public prominence (and to a confrontation with the PtB). It's not really a *short* story, though it's not that long either.